# Youtube service authorisation

Tags: youtube-api

I need to make some private Youtube channel videos available to users on my ASP.NET website. These videos should be made available to all authenticated users with appropriate access rights (which are internal to my website). I want then to programmatically authenticate those users to Youtube using my company's Google account so they can watch videos.

I cannot seem to find any Google API documentation article which supports this scenario. Please advise if this is possible?

To clarify my task - I don't want my website's users to interactively login to Google as it's the company's Google account which has access to the private Youtube channel.

Comment: Someone at the company will need to authenticate the code the first time the YouTube API only supports public api keys and Oauth2.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you, what do you mean by "authenticate the code the first time"?

Comment: Login and grant the application access, once your application has been granted access you save the refresh token you can then use the refresh token to get an access token later. .   You should read about Oauth2 http://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-oauth2/

Comment: Thanks for providing some input, but the "Login and grant..." is something I cannot do as far as I understand. I cannot login the web user interactively as they should not have account details of my company's account which stores the videos. And I cannot log them in programmatically behind the scenes as OAuth requires interactive login.

Comment: You have access correct?  You run the app the first time personally authenticate it.  Save the refresh token.  User runs the app you get the stored refreshtoken access the account do what needs to be done.  This will work and is your only option unfortunately.